# RDS does not support creating a DB instance with the following combination

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

I'm trying to figure out how to create a simple DB instance. I have so far only a `DBSubnetGroup` and `DBInstance`. At this point, I've figured out a couple things based on the errors I get when I try to create a stack with my template (created in Designer).

I've now hit an error that, according to the instance class documentation it appears like it should be supported, but I guess not. Based on my snippet below, what should I be using instead?

```
myDB:
  Type: 'AWS::RDS::DBInstance'
  Properties:
    DBInstanceClass: db.m1.small
    DBName: myDB
    DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref myDBSubnetGroup
    Engine: mysql
    EngineVersion: 5.6.41
    AllocatedStorage: '100'
    MasterUsername: admin
    MasterUserPassword: AmazingPassword
```

The actual error is

```
RDS does not support creating a DB instance with the following combination: DBInstanceClass=db.m1.small, Engine=mysql, EngineVersion=5.6.41, LicenseModel=general-public-license. For supported combinations of instance class and database engine version, see teh documentation. (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID: 04a8be38-9368-40e4-b677-1cdc442b3cae
```

Again, I've looked at the documentation and it says that db.m1.small supports MySQL v5.6. Perhaps that is out of date? I guess I can try 5.7.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I think it could be because db.m1.* series is an old instance type. Can you try using one of the current generation instance type like db.m5.* or db.t3.* or db.t2.* (for free tier eligible).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Taken from the AWS documentation:

> You can only create MySQL version 5.7 and 8.0 DB instances with
> latest-generation and current-generation DB instance classes, in
> addition to the db.m3 previous-generation DB instance class.

Read more: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.MySQL.html

In case you are running an Aurora cluster, different instance class restrictions apply.

Read more about Aurora instance class: https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Concepts.DBInstanceClass.html

Comment: Thanks. I missed that.

Comment: Incase anyone else has made the same mistake I made, aurora-mysql has different instance restrictions to plain MySQL. You can find these here: https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Concepts.DBInstanceClass.html

Comment: @AnisJonischkeit I edited the answer to include your comment. Thanks, it helped solve my problem. My problem was, that Aurora is not available for `db.*.small` instance classes.

Answer (score 10):

You can always go the the AWS console and try to manually create a RDS instance. Select the DB version you want and it will filter the supported instance types for you.

Comment: Very helpful to avoid choosing an incompatible instance class, as I was not easily able to find the exact list of instance classes supported by MySQL 8.x. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I believe here you can find the full list to check which DBClassInstance is compatible with your desired DB: [AWS - Supported DB engines for DB instance classes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.DBInstanceClass.html#Concepts.DBInstanceClass.Support)

Comment: This page has aws CLI examples too that give you the exact info you need.