# RDS upgrade postgres version 13.1, unsupported DB Instance Class

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds

I'm trying to upgrade from version 12.5 to the version 13.1 in RDS. But I'm receiving an error similar to the one described in this question: [RDS does not support creating a DB instance with the following combination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55598030/rds-does-not-support-creating-a-db-instance-with-the-following-combination). As far as I understand in order to upgrade a proper version `DB instance class` should be selected. However the error message shows a previous selection, not a new one. Same message is received in Terraform setting up

```
engine_version    = "13.1"
instance_class    = "db.t3.small"
```

Screenshot from AWS showing the changes and message:
[image]

Copied error message to make it easier to research:

> We're sorry, your request to modify DB instance [service-name] has failed.
> RDS does not support creating a DB instance with the following combination: DBInstanceClass=db.t2.small, Engine=postgres, EngineVersion=13.1, LicenseModel=postgresql-license. For supported combinations of instance class and database engine version, see the documentation.

Is there some key to `allow_instance_class_change` (a made up key)  or something else I overlooked what prevents an upgrade? Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest upgrading to T3 first, then upgrading to PostgreSQL 13. If you need to do those at the same time you might have better luck going through the API, but I'm guessing the way the version 13 upgrade works you need to already be on a supported instance type for the upgrade to proceed.

Comment: Yes, indeed, that's what I'm trying to do, two changes: 1) version 13; 2) db instance class. You can see it on the screenshot attached to the question

Comment: @Georgy sorry I didn't see all the information in your question at first. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, thank you, that's what I'm trying to do right now, upgrading an instance first on 12.5. Thanks!